# Why do I get this error - Compiled with problems: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-top-loading-bar' while installing top-loading-bar

Tags: reactjs, visual-web-developer

I want a top loading bar on my page but I keep getting a bunch of errors when I tried to install the npm.
this is the command I used-

```js
npm install --save react-top-loading-bar
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and the errors in my terminal-

[picture of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xEUj.png)

and the error on my browser

[picture of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne06L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are upstream dependency issues from the package you're trying to fetch while your project has a different version of react.

I get these a lot too with older packages now while working in react 18 projects.

You can install with a force:

```
npm install --save react-top-loading-bar -f
```